# Magento2: Many .js requests. How do I merge js files?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I see over 130 requests to retrieve .js files, and I think it is a reason why the magento2 site is so slow. How can I optimize it? I've already set merge and bundle js files in admin, but it's not helping. I've enabled product -s mode, ran di:compile etc. Still the same. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Could you find solution? @Pribhav

Comment: @Khushbu I get it resolved by installing Potato Compressor extension in my site. Now, merging is working well and site speed gets improved.

Comment: @Pribhav thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **setup:di:compile** does not refer or affect in any way javascript files. It refers to **Dependency Injection** which is another topic.

**Magento** by default is known to be robust and use a lot of resources.

On the topic of js bundling this article might help:

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/javascript-bundling-magento-2/

Another performance improvement might be using Redis for **Page Caching** or **Session Caching**

Information about configuring **Redis** can be found in the official docs

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable javascript bundling.
See [official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html) how to do this

Comment: I've already done it

Comment: Also you need to enable production mode